# monacaでandroidアプリ用のキーストアが作成できません

Tags: android, monaca

monacaでandroidアプリ用のキーストアを作成しようとすると、「Fail to create key store」とエラーが表示されてしまい、一向に作成ができません。
2バイト文字は使っていないのですが、何が原因なのかご存知の方はいらっしゃいますでしょうか？

使用している環境は
MacOS X 10.10.5 Chrome
になります。

恐れ入りますが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: キーストアの作成方法と、何にエラーが出ているのか知りたいです（コンソールなのか、Web上のダイアログなのか）。[Androidキーストアの作成方法](http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/ja/manual/build/build_android/)の手順でしょうか？

Comment: @quesera2  コメントありがとうございました。
キーストアの生成は、設定メニューの「Androidキーストア生成」から行っております。
エラーはMonaca IDEのエラーとしてダイアログに表示されております。
また、仰るとおり、Androidキーストアの作成方法の手順になります。

なお、先ほどWindows＆Chrome、Firefoxで試しても同様の事象が発生しました。
何かアプリの設定などが足りてないのですかね・・・。

Comment: キーストアを作成する上で、アプリ側に特別な設定は不要なはずです。というのも、これはJava SDKに付属している[keytool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/6/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html)を使って証明書と鍵を管理するキーストアを生成しているだけだからです。外部でキーストアを作成して、インポートしてみるというのも手かもしれません。

Comment: @quesera2 返信頂きまして、誠にありがとうございました。
なるほど、裏ではkeytoolを実行しているだけなんですね・・・。
昔Eclipseで作ったアプリを公開した時に使用したkeynoteをインポートしてみたのですが、全く同じ種類のエラーが表示されました。
次は別の方法でキーストアを作って、改めてインポートを試してみたいと思います。
色々とありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

こちら、サービス側の不具合でした。
テクニカルサポートに連絡し、無事に対応頂きました。

お騒がせいたしました。